# ArrayList::new taking more time than k->new ArrayList<>() in computeIfAbsent method of map

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, hashmap

I have a requirement to group a list of object based on some member of the object. Let me show the requirement through an example what i want to achieve:

I have a **UserStage** class:

```
public class UserStage {

    private Integer userId;
    private Integer stageId;
    private LocalDateTime modifiedOn;

   //getter, setter and toString methods
}
```

Now let's say i have a `List<UserStage>` which can have multiple object for same userId. Let's call it **userStageDataList**.

I want to group this list by userId, so that i can get list of all records for a particular userId. This can be achieved by different approaches, but the way i tried to achieve this was as following:

```
Map<Integer, List<UserStage>> userWiseStageList = new HashMap<>();
        
for (UserStage userStage : userStageDataList) {
    userWiseStageList.computeIfAbsent(userStage.getUserId(), ArrayList::new).add(userStage);
}
```

But what surprised me here was that it was constantly taking around 3000ms to excute this for just 75 items in the list. And sometimes it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

When i replaced `ArrayList::new` with `k -> new ArrayList<>()` and now it was taking just 3 to 4 ms to create the grouping.

I tried `groupingBy` using `streams` and that also excuted well within 5-7ms for the same list.

I used following code to measure the execution time:

```
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
watch.start();
// here goes map creation code as shown above
logger.info("\n\n\n time taken for creating the map = {}",watch.getTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

*Am i missing something here? Any suggestions would be appreciated!*

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. `map.computeIfAbsent(k, func)` will invoke `func` with argument `k` if `map` doesn't has key `k`.
2. function`ArrayList::new` accepts an argument `initialCapacity`, which will be the initial size of the backing array of the List

So, in your case, if userId `1000` is absent in the map, the program will execute `new ArrayList<>(1000)` to create an ArrayList backed by an `Object[]` of size `1000`. That is why it takes longer time and sometime consumes all VM memory.